# Terrible has_child query performance

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query has terrible performance.

100% sure it is the has_child. Query without it runs under 300ms, with it it takes 9 seconds.

Is there some better way to use the **has_child** query? It seems like I could query parents, and then children by id and then join client side to do the has child check faster than the ES database engine is doing it...

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "has_child": {
                                "type": "status",
                                "query": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "stage": "s3"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "has_child": {
                                "type": "status",
                                "query": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "stage": "es"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "source": "IntegrationTest-2016-03-01T23:31:15.023Z"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "eventTimestamp": {
                                    "from": "2016-03-01T20:28:15.028Z",
                                    "to": "2016-03-01T23:33:15.028Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "digests": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "digest",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Cluster info:
CPU and memory usage is low. It is AWS ES Service cluster (v1.5.2). Many small documents, and since version aws is running is old, doc values aren't on by default. Not sure if that is helping or hurting.

Comment: Is "stage" an analyzed field? Just curious if you could optimize a bit by using a `has_child` *filter* instead of query.

Comment: @BrookeB "stage" is indexed but not analyzed. Do you mean make the internal "query" into "filter" instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I bit the bullet and just performed the parent:child join in my application. Instead of waiting 7 seconds for the has_child query, I fire off two consecutive term queries and do some post processing: 200ms.

Answer (score 1):

Since "stage" is not analyzed (based on your comment) and, therefore, you are not interested in scoring the documents that match on that field, you might realize slight performance gains by using the `has_child` **filter** instead of the `has_child` *query*. And using a `term` **filter** instead of a `term` *query*.

In the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-has-child-filter.html) for `has_child`, you'll notice:

> The has_child filter also accepts a filter instead of a query:

The main performance benefits of using a filter come from the fact that Elasticsearch can skip the scoring phase of the query. Also, filters can be cached which should improve the performance of future searches that use the same filters. Queries, on the other hand, cannot be cached.

Try this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "source": "IntegrationTest-2016-03-01T23:31:15.023Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "eventTimestamp": {
                  "from": "2016-03-01T20:28:15.028Z",
                  "to": "2016-03-01T23:33:15.028Z"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "status",
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "stage": "s3"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "status",
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "stage": "es"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "digests": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "digest",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it performs about the same whether using filter or query. It seems like the has_child query is just really slow. I have tested on faster hardware, more/less nodes in cluster and it made no difference

Comment: @smashbourne Bummer. I have heard others with performance issues on parent/child documents. I think they made improvements in 2.x, perhaps will work better for you in the future.